# Chrome History - possible to see date of each visit / restore history to a previous date?

Tags: google-chrome

In google chrome, the history overwrites old visits upon each new visit of a specific site. This is a problem as it's impossible to see which sites were visited on a specific date (as the history can move the sites to a more recent date).

However, the history keeps track of how many times a site was visited.

Question: Does the history also keep track of all the dates a specific site was visited? Further, is it possible to restore the history so that it removes the newer visits than specific date X?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Google's My Activity](https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity) webpage, since it list all website you visit from chrome/Android devices, ...

You can use the search feature for a specific URL and remove a specific website from your Google activity. This assume you browsed on chrome while logged in your Google account.